# What locale LC_CTYPE is used for Windows unicode console app?

Tags: c, utf-16, windows-console

While converting a multi-byte console application to Unicode, I ran up against a weird problem where `_tcprintf` and `WriteConsole` worked fine but `_tprintf` was printing the wrong characters...

I've traced it back to using `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")` which uses `LC_CTYPE` of 1 byte based on MS doc:

> The C locale assumes that all char data types are 1 byte and that their value is always less than 256.

However, *I want to keep `"C"` for everything except the `LC_CTYPE` but I don't know what to use?*

I thought the whole point of using UTF16 is that all the characters are available and things would print properly no matter the code page or locale.

Although it also appears setting the console output to UTF-8 (65001) (`SetConsoleCP` which of course is separate from the locale) in a Unicode app and outputting UTF16 also has problems displaying the correct characters.

Anyway, does anyone know what value I should be using the `LC_CTYPE` for UTF16 on Windows Unicode Console Application?  Maybe it's as easy as `setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "" );` ? TIA!!

Comment: Why voluntarily use utf16 in 2018?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [_setmode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2017) to set the file translation mode to `_O_U16TEXT`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"ελληνικά\n");
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! I actually had just trace the wprintf call and saw that some mode had to be set.  Do you know where it is documented?

Comment: @user3161924 Doesn't the sample code int the MSDN page i linked count as documentation?

Comment: My VS2008 docs don't have that for _setmode(), but works.  I'd expect the docs to have it on the wprintf() type page or a generic using unicode page.  If it doesn't exist, that's fine, I just thought if there was, it could provide more details on other things as well.

Comment: @user3161924 Why are you using Visual Studio 20**0**8 in 20**1**8?